# Rails 5: How can I see a model with via 2 models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I do `@post = Post.first.comments.build(content: "bla", user: @user)` and search via `@user.comments` nothing shows up. But when I do it with `@post.comments`, it lists the comment. How can I see my comment with both `@user.comments` and `@post.comments`?

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :comments      
end
```

my user model

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :posts
    has_many :comments
end
```

comment model

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :post
end
```

Comment: `.build` merely instantiates a new record - it does not save the record to the DB. It is an alias for `.new`.  So when you do `@user.comments` it queries the database and does not care about the new record you created in memory only.

Comment: `@comment = Post.first.comments.create(content: "bla", user: @user); @comment  == @user.comments.last` on the other hand will accomplish what you are looking for.

Comment: thx @max it worked, though not sure why `build` did not work

Comment: Read the first comment...

Answer (score 0):

use `through` to get comments of all posts associated with the user's posts.

```
class User
  has_many :posts
  has_many :comments, through: :posts
end
```